# set image if php doesn't answer in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script in php to create a graph (with jpgraph) and I use javascript to set that image in my page:

```
$("#page_image").attr('src', "generate_graph.php");
```

Sometimes my server doesn't work and I got a green image telling me the error and others I got just a crash icon image (not image found or so).

Is it possible to set a timeout and if after some seconds I got nothing, set a backup image already created?

Or, must I do it in php server side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fallback for 404 images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439024/fallback-for-404-images)

Comment: What about using `onerror` html attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use .load() with setTimeout()

```js
$(function(){

  var imageLoadTimeout = 1000; // millisecs
  
  // Timeout, if image not loaded in imageLoadTimeout time then we display error.jpg
  var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     $("#page_image").attr("src", "error.jpg");
  }, imageLoadTimeout);
  
  
  $("#page_image").load(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);  // if image loaded sucessfully, clear the timeout
  });
  
  $("#page_image").attr("src", "generate_graph.php"); // Try to load image
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="page_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try error event:

```
$("#page_image").attr('src', "generate_graph.php").on('error', function() {
   $(this).attr('src', 'defaultimage.png');
});
```